# Android: Placing ImageView on overlap between layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to place an `ImageView` on the overlap point between two layouts. In the picture below, my goal would be to place the `ImageView` where the white square is.  **NOTE: The overlap point will not necessarily be centered vertically as shown below**

[image]

Is this possible in XML?

My only guess right now is to do this in the actual code itself.

EDIT 8/3/2016: For reference, I think `ConstraintLayouts` may be the best future solution for these types of problems http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-editor

Comment: Yes, is possible. Using Layout Start

Comment: What is 'layout start'? Can you link me to the Android documentation for this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_START

Comment: You need use a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I want to center on an edge, not start on an edge, I am still confused

Comment: Yes, its possible

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This will do what you want, with either an image of fixed height, or calculated programatically.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/layoutTop" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overlapImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/layoutBottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp" <!-- This should be always half the height, can also be calculated and added programtically -->
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @paul how to design the same layout using material design(CollapsingToolbarLayout and NestedScrollView)

Comment: it's not generic, it should be used `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this won't work for layouts of different sizes

Answer (score 0):

use constraint layout
then assume there is a top_view and bottom_view
you want to place the view between top_view and bottom_view

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_size_100"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/middle_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/top_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_view">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="abcd" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ipsum" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity2"
android:orientation="vertical"
>



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layouttop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dhaka"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    >



</RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutbutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layouttop"
    >


</RelativeLayout>




<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagemiddle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/man"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutbutton"
    />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).