# How to set my circleImageView on the border of my layout in android?

Tags: android

Explanation:
            I want to set my circleImageView on the border of my layout.

Here is my xml file in which there are more layout but i want to set circleimageview on the border of the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.Registration">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="25dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/viewA"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:background="@color/login_header"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/symbol"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp"
                        android:text="@string/Holiday"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/symbol"
                        android:textColor="@color/header_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20sp"/>

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/circleView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/circularimage"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/viewB"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/fab_tint"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:contentDescription="@null"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_username"/>

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                                android:hint="@string/hint_name" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:contentDescription="@null"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_email" />

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/input_email"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                                android:hint="@string/hint_email" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:contentDescription="@null"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:src="@drawable/lock_open" />

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:inputType="textPassword"
                                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                                android:hint="@string/hint_password" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/btn_select"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:background="@color/btn_start_color"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_white"/>

                    </FrameLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/btn_signup"
                            android:layout_weight="0.7"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_round"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is an demo image i want exactly like this

[image]

Please, help me to solve out.

Comment: **i want to set circleimageview on the border of the layout**. Could you explain specific where  you want it.

Comment: see my image i want exactly like that

Comment: Please Try These Answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127468/android-placing-imageview-on-overlap-between-layouts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864422/android-imageview-overlay-another-imageview

Comment: What is current Scenario with your code ? post that screen also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="15dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.angelnx.angelnx.holidays.Registration">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inner_relativelayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/inner_relativelayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/symbol"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/HomeFragmentProfileImageView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            android:src="@drawable/circularImage" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ProjectNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/HomeFragmentProfileImageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Profile"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/fab_tint"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_username" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_name"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_email" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/lock_open" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/btn_start_color"
                    android:text="@string/btn_select"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_white"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_round"
                    android:text="@string/btn_signup"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an xml in your drawable folder e.g. round_image_holder.xml and write following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />

<size
    android:width="80dp"
    android:height="80dp" />
<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Then use this shape round_image_holder as your imageView backgroung. Something like this.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/round_image_holder"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

make one xml in your drawable folder:
round_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval">

<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<size
    android:height="80dp"
    android:width="80dp" />

<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />
</shape>
```

activitiy_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.oval.MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/inner_relativelayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/HomeFragmentCoverImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#3b5271" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/HomeFragmentProfileImageView"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:background="@drawable/round_image"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

hope it will work for you